# Pivot groups of row values into columns in R

Tags: r, dataset, logic, layout

I have a dataframe in R like this (C1 and C2 the columns):

```
C1      C2  
1       A  
1       H   
1       C   
2       D   
2       R      
2       G  
3       Z    
3       L   
3       M
```

I would like to have it this way:

```
1   2    3   
A   D    Z   
H   R    L   
C   G    M
```

None of the options I have tried are giving me this layout.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can be useful:

```
X <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)
Y <- c("A","H","C","D","R","G","Z","L","M")
DF <- data.frame(C1=X, C2=Y)
DF
```

$$
C1 \,C2\\
1 \, A \\
1 \, H \\
1 \, C \\
2 \, D \\
2 \, R \\
2 \, G \\
3 \, Z \\
3  \, L \\
3 \, M \\
$$

```
t <- NULL 
for (i in 1:max(X)){
t[[i]] <-   DF$C2[which(DF$C1 %in% i)]
}

TDF <- data.frame("1"= t[[1]], "2" = t[[2]], "3" = t[[3]])
TDF
```

$$
 X1 \, X2 \,  X3 \\
 A \, D  \, Z \\
 H \, R \, L \\
 C \, G \, M \\
$$

Answer (score 0):

First off, your question, as stated, has no solution, because you cannot use integers as column names.

But more importantly, what you want to do doesn't actually make sense in terms of "tidy" data.

In tidy data, each row is supposed to represent a unique "observation". However, in the original dataframe you give, there is no association between the set {A, D, Z}, and as well for the other rows in your target dataframe. Consequently, **no** set of tidy operations will to what you want.

However, if you create another column that associates them, you can use that column in the `spread` operator to get what you want.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 = data.frame(
  C1 = rep(c(1,2,3), each=3),
  C2 = LETTERS[1:9]
)

df1 %>%  spread(C1, C2)
#> Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.
#> Keys are shared for 9 rows:
#> * 1, 2, 3
#> * 4, 5, 6
#> * 7, 8, 9

df2 = data.frame(
  C1 = rep(c(1,2,3), each=3),
  C2 = LETTERS[1:9],
  C3 = rep(c(1,2,3), times=3)
)

df2 %>% spread(C3, C2)
#>   C1 1 2 3
#> 1  1 A B C
#> 2  2 D E F
#> 3  3 G H I
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>